# How to create a Windows user suitable for installing db2 server with extended security?

Tags: db2, windows-server, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I'm trying to install db2 10.5 on Windows Server 2008 not as built-in "Administrator", but as another local user, but it fails to create instance with the symptoms similar to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC85663

First it complains it cannot create `DB2ADMNS` and `DB2USERS` groups (in fact, the groups appear after installer dies)

Then there's a another mesage:

> The creation of the process for the partitioned instance failed.
>   Return value is "4294965337".

I don't have Active Directory. All users are local. Here's how I create the user for installing db2:

```
net user db2installer s3cret /ADD
net localgroup Administrators db2installer /add
```

I don's see any difference between "Administrator" and "db2installer". Perhaps "db2installer" should be added to some security policy?

Comment: Did you try the workarounds suggested in the article you link to? Did they work? Also, try installing with a user whose name is 8 characters or shorter (and which is a local administrator, obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by setting

```
 Security options/User Account Control: run all administrators in admin approval mode = Disabled
```

in Local Security Policy